# Scala:How to convert my input to list of list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have the below input,

input

```
[level:1,firstFile:one,secondFile:secone,Flag:NA][level:1,firstFile:two,secondFile:sectwo,Flag:NA][level:2,firstFile:three,secondFile:secthree,Flag:NA]
```

getting below output and working fine,

```
List(List(one, two), List(three))
List(List(secone, sectwo), List(secthree))
```

However when i pass the below input i am getting the output as,

```
[level:1,firstFile:one,four,secondFile:secone,Flag:NA][level:1,firstFile:two,secondFile:sectwo,Flag:NA][level:2,firstFile:three,secondFile:secthree,Flag:NA]
```

getting output as,

```
List(List(), List(two), List(three))
List(List(), List(sectwo), List(secthree))
```

But the expected output is,

```
List(List(one, four, two), List(three))
List(List(secone, sectwo), List(secthree))
```

Code.

```
 val validJsonRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(input)).flatMap(x => x.replace(",", "\",\"").replace(":", "\":\"").replace("[", "{\"").replace("]", "\"}").replace("}{", "}&{").split("&"))
        import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
        val df = spark.read.json(validJsonRdd).orderBy("level").groupBy("level")
                .agg(collect_list("firstFile").as("firstFile"), collect_list("secondFile").as("secondFile"))
                .select(collect_list("firstFile").as("firstFile"), collect_list("secondFile").as("secondFile"))          

        val rdd = df.collect().map(row => (row(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]], row(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]]))
        val first = rdd(0)._1.map(x => x.toList).toList       
        val second = rdd(0)._2.map(x => x.toList).toList

     val firstInputcolumns =  first.map(_.filterNot(_ == null)) 
     val secondInputcolumns= second.map(_.filterNot(_ == null))
     println(firstInputcolumns)
     println(secondInputcolumns)
```

Kindly help me to correct the code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your replaces are quite producing valid JSON. If you run them on the second input, for the first entry you get:

```
{"level":"1","firstFile":"one","four","secondFile":"secone","Flag":"NA"}
```

But JSON is a list of key-value pairs. You can't just have "four" sitting out on its own like that. If you want **firstFile** to be mapped to a list, one and four should be wrapped in square brackets, and the JSON should look like so:

```
{"level":"1","firstFile":["one","four"],"secondFile":"secone","Flag":"NA"}
```